# I'd like to stick to using "the same girl as the one who~ " because it is wordy but sounds more specific

Tags: sentence-construction

Here's the context.

A girl talked to John yesterday.

I met a girl in the library today.

The two girls are the same person.

> 1. The girl who talked to John yesterday is the same person as the one that I met in the library today.
> 2. I met the same girl in the library as the one who talked to John yesterday.
> 3. The same girl as the one who talked to John yesterday is the person that I met in the library today.

Personally I'd like to stick to using "the same girl as the one who~ " because it is wordy but sounds more specific. So I think all of them are possible to use. And here, I'd like to make sentences as diversely as possible and I'd like to know these mean the same and possible to use.

Comment: possible duplicate of [The same girl + as the one who / as / that - preference?](http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/62677/the-same-girl-as-the-one-who-as-that-preference)

Comment: ...who *was talking* to John yesterday. You don't need "the same". "is" has all the power it needs.  "The girl I met in the library is the (same) one who was talking to John yesterday."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All the sentences make sense, but I think you use a lot of words that can be dropped.  If I were in your place, I would say the following:

1. The girl who talked to John yesterday is the same as I met in the library today or is the one I met.........
2. ........ is the one John talked to yesterday or is the same as John talked to yesterday.
3. The same girl who talked to John is the one....

Answer (score 2):

You are using "the same one as" where you should use "the same one". Your 3 choices ought to be

1. The girl who talked to John yesterday is the same one who I met in the library today.
2. I met the same girl who talked to John yesterday in the library.
3. The girl who talked to John yesterday is the same one I met in the library today.

"The same as" establishes equality or equivalence. In all 3 cases you are establishing identity, which is not the same. That is, the girl who talked to John is not "the same as" the one I met today, she is "the same one".

That said, "the same one as" is fairly common in informal speech.